# Automation Error - The Object Invoked has Disconnected from It Clients during autofilter

Tags: vba, excel, windows-7, excel-2013

Ok, I know there are many posts about this but so far none of them have a solution that seems to work for me.

I ran across this for the first time a week ago and have created a very simple program to try and figure out what is going on. I have resorted to hand typing all this (I usually start with an old macro and modify it or copy and past code pieces); I have made my own data file just in case there was something weird with the file I am planning to use as the input; and it still errors out.

I have other macros that are doing the exact same processes and they still work fine. This is driving me insane. The code below crashes on the Autofilter line.

```
Sub Fred()
Dim strFileToOpen As String
Dim wbHL7 As Workbook
    strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please select the Invoice file.", FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")
    If strFileToOpen = "False" Then
        MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set wbHL7 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFileToOpen)
    End If
    rCnt = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K" & rCnt).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=0, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K" & rCnt).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Many of the other posts hint that there might be an issue with my actual system such as compatibility things, but then why are the other macros still working? By the way, once it does this, it basically locks up everything to do with Excel and I have to open the Task Manager to kill the process. I am using Windows 7 and Office 2013.

Edit:

I just want to add that if I record an autofilter macro in the same book as the data, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your code. The criteria needs to be a string. If you look carefully at the recorded macro you'll see that it too uses a string.

Change your autofilter line to the following and it should work:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K" & rCnt).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="=0", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Well that was pretty simple. If it hadn't been such a "You really messed up and nothing is going to work anymore" kind of error, it would have been a little easier to figure out.

Comment: @Jay typical crazy Micro$oft error for you. I can't make any sense of it.